# Recreating moire patterns in geometry nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, geometry-nodes

Recreating moire patterns **in geometry nodes**

**I'm trying to recreate an answer given in Animation Nodes to Geometry Nodes.**

The original question and answer / link. [Converting code to work in blender with sliders](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112423/converting-code-to-work-in-blender-with-sliders)

[image: img1]

Now I'm trying to do the same thing using **Geometry Nodes**
When I use the offset on the "arms" the "skew" seems to be off / to rigid.

[image: img 2]

Answer (score 9):

Here's one way to do it:

[image]

1. Create a base mesh with a bunch of grids instanced on a line. The grids have a size of 1, so i space out the line points by 2 to make an odd/even pattern. I give them some more resolution on the Y axis for later twisting, can be tweaked as needed. [image]
2. Then "realize" those instances. That will turn it into a full mesh so i can place each vertex where it needs to go. [image]
3. Then a *SetPosition* node to turn this array into an actual spiral. First step is to scale it so all points sit on the Y axis, between inner and out radius.[image]
4. Then i rotate the vector to make a basic fan, using the original X position mapped to 2*pi range.[image]
5. And finally add the twist by adding an angle proportional to the Y position.[image]